# what's wrong in this react-bootstrap carousel component?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a carousel by react-bootstrap and i have a problem rendering it on my page:

This is part of my code:

```
this.slides.map((slide, index) => ({
    <Carousel.Item >
       <Row className="item-container carousel-item d-flex flex-xl-column flex-wrap">
          {
            slide.map(category => { // slide is not defined
               return (                                            
                 <Col className="px-2 category__card" xl={category.xl} md={category.md}>
                   <Card className="p-2" style={category.style}>
                       <Card.Body>
                         <Card.Title className="text-white font-weight-normal text-uppercase ">
                           <h4>
                              category.title}
                           </h4>
                         </Card.Title>
                         <Button variant="light rounded-0" >View Products</Button>    
                      </Card.Body>
                      <div className="card-image-cont">
                         <Card.Img  src={category.img} className="card-image"/>
                      </div> 
                   </Card>  
                 </Col>
              );
            })
          }
       </Row>
    </Carousel.Item> 
 }))
```

You can imagine data is like this:

```
slides = [
   [
     {
       title: 'laptops',
       img: images.laptop,
       md: 6,
       xl: 3,
       style: {
         "background": "red",
         "height": "100%"
       }
     },


    {

       title: 'mobiles',
       img: images.mobile,
       md: 6,
       xl: 4,
       style: {
         "background": "#c4dd60",
         "height": "100%",
         "margin-bottom": "0.5em;"
       }
    }
 ],
 [
     {
       title: 'laptops',
       img: images.laptop,
       md: 6,
       xl: 3,
       style: {
         "background": "red",
         "height": "100%"
       }
     },


    {

       title: 'mobiles',
       img: images.mobile,
       md: 6,
       xl: 4,
       style: {
         "background": "#c4dd60",
         "height": "100%",
         "margin-bottom": "0.5em;"
       }
    }
 ]

]
```

I get this error `slide is not defined`, what's wrong i am doing here? i am looping through each item in `slides` to create more than one carousel item 
 and each carousel item should contain multiple categories but do not know why i get this error..may be something i am not understanding about **JSX**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has at least 2 problems.

The first one is that there is an extra bracket: `this.slides.map((slide, index) => ({ ... }))` should be `this.slides.map((slide, index) => { ... })`.

And the second one is that you return nothing in your outer `map()` function: `this.slides.map((slide, index) => { ... })` should be `this.slides.map((slide, index) => { return ( ... ) })`. As a result (assuming that your whole code is wrapped in `return()` method), your code will look like this:

```
this.slides.map((slide, index) => {
    return (
     <Carousel.Item>
       <Row className="item-container carousel-item d-flex flex-xl-column flex-wrap">
          {
            slide.map(category => { // slide is not defined
               return (                                            
                 <Col className="px-2 category__card" xl={category.xl} md={category.md}>
                   <Card className="p-2" style={category.style}>
                       <Card.Body>
                         <Card.Title className="text-white font-weight-normal text-uppercase ">
                           <h4>
                              category.title}
                           </h4>
                         </Card.Title>
                         <Button variant="light rounded-0" >View Products</Button>    
                      </Card.Body>
                      <div className="card-image-cont">
                         <Card.Img  src={category.img} className="card-image"/>
                      </div> 
                   </Card>  
                 </Col>
              );
            })
          }
       </Row>
    </Carousel.Item> 
)})
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/9dfbq1n8/) is a simple example based on your code. Hope this helps you.